# Reliable and fast communication between Python script and Android app

Tags: android, python, sockets, communication

I'm working on a project, where the reliable and fast(100 times/sec) communication between the app and the script is important. I've implemented Socket communication on both sides, but if the Android app sends data to the Python script, sometimes (cca 1-2 times from 10), there is an error, and the Python script cannot parse the recieved data correctly. For example, there is a value error when sending: `FLAG::val1::val2::val3` or `FLAG::val1` repeatedly.

Here how I implemented the Python socket server:

```
class Connection():  
def __init__(self): 
    self.connected = False        

def start_connention(self):
    host = '192.168.42.1'
    port = 8888

    self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)         

    #Bind socket to local host and port
    try:
        self.server.bind((host, port))
    except socket.error, msg:
        print 'Bind failed. Error code: ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
        sys.exit()  

    #Start listening on socket
    self.server.listen(10)
    print 'Socket now listening on ' + str(port)

    self.connection, addr = self.server.accept()
    print 'Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])                

    #Disable blocking
    self.connection.settimeout(0.0)        

    self.connected = True                     

def read(self):
    try:
        data = self.connection.recv(4096).split("::")
    except:
        data = ["N"] #no data
    return data

def send(self, message):
    self.connection.sendall(message)

def close(self):
    print("closing")
    self.connected = False
    self.server.close()
```

Here is the Android code snippet sending the SeekBar's values:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener{

SeekBar sbSpeed;

Socket socket;
BufferedReader reader;
PrintWriter writer;
Communication communication;

boolean connected = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sbSpeed = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sbSpeed);
    sbSpeed.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

    communication = new Communication(); 
    // the Thread is started when clicking on a button
}

class Communication implements Runnable{
    public PrintWriter writer;
    public BufferedReader reader;
    public Socket socket;
    public boolean ok;

    public Communication(){
        ok = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{                
            socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("192.168.42.1"), 8888);
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
            while(ok){
                String line = reader.readLine(); 
                //parse the line...
            }                                               
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}    

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar sb, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    String text  = "SPEED::" + progress; 

    communication.writer.write(text);
    communication.writer.flush();

    tvSpeed.setText(progress + "");
}
```

Is there a better way of communication? What should be changed in the program to avoid errors during the communication?

EDIT: example added. Assume that this method is in the Connection class.

```
def example():
    while True:
        user_data = read()
        if user_data[0] == "SPEED":
            speed = int(user_data[1]) # HERE IS THE VALUEERROR THROWN
```

EDIT:
[image: ValueError at last line]

Comment: the line `data = self.connection.recv(4096).split("::")` looks suspect to me. as it's possible to read a partial message that way.  perhaps buffer the messages up to a termination character for individual messages or have a fixed message length.

Comment: 'there is an error, and the Python script cannot parse the recieved data correctly.'. What error exactly? And how does the received data look at that moment? 'coommunication.writer.write(text);
    communication.writer.flush();'. I do not understand that those statements are possible there as you execute them on the main thread.

Comment: 'FLAG::val1::val2::val3 '. There is nothing in your code that sends such formatted strings.

Comment: @greenapps: Python throws ValueError when recieving data too fast.
FLAG::val1 is like String text  = "SPEED::" + progress;

Comment: What is a value error? I asked for an example. Why arent you giving an example?

Comment: 'FLAG::val1::val2::val3 '. There is nothing in your code that sends such formatted strings. '. You are not coming to the point. Nothing in your code will send such formatted strings. The server could receive though "SEND::val1SEND::val2SEND::val3" or a part of it. You are not separating a send value from the next SEND. So i can imagine that you have a value error when taking the value of val2SEND. FOR EXAMPLE!

Comment: I've added an example.
Yes, you're right, I'm not separating the send value from the next SEND, the probem is exactly, what you've written: val2SEND

Comment: Just send back a message from server when the parsing is done. Can you post the code where you run the server?

Comment: 'I've added an example. '. No you have not. You only added the code that gives the error. If you had given an example you would have stated the contents of user_data, user_data[0] and user_data[1].

Comment: I've reproduced it, and now, you can see: user_data[0] is SPEED, user_data[1] is the value between 1000 and 2000.
The ValueError occures at the last line, where user_data[1] is 1457SPEED

Comment: So now you know how you can solve this.